# Error in connecting to sql Server Management Studio2014

Tags: sql-server

I have trouble with connecting to SQL Server.
SQL shows me this error whenever I press Connect button:

### **TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-CAVOQPL.
------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: Is that a correct server name ?

Comment: Update: I used to work with the same server name (DESKTOP-CAVOQPL) without any problem.

Comment: Is this your local server ? Can you please open command prompt and Type `SQLCMD -L` and see list of the servers and see whether that list contains 'DESKTOP-CAVOQPL' server

Comment: I can't see any server name!!

Comment: It's driving me mad!

Comment: Can you open RUN box and type - services.msc and check whether your SQL server is running

Comment: Servers:
    ;UID:Login ID=?;PWD:Password=?;Trusted_Connection:Use Integrated Security=?;*APP:AppName=?;*WSID:WorkStation ID=?;

Comment: Is your SQL server service is up and running ?

Comment: This service is not running? I can't see it.

Comment: Can you please right click on it and click on start

Comment: And also go to properties -> set startup Type to automatic

Comment: My sql window is open. How can I check it's up and running?

Comment: Can you open cmd prompt and type `SQLCMD -L` and see the server name. Get that server and copy paste it in server name of SQL window

Comment: My MSSQLSERVER was not running, so I started it. now I'm connected to sql server. THANK YOU dear friend.

Comment: I will answer this question. make it as ans

Answer (score 1):

The problem was your service was not running. 
Open Run and type -`services.msc` and start SQL server. Also Right click on it and go to properties and set startuptype to automatic.